# String replace and arraylist performance on large objects

Tags: android, string, arraylist, replace

I am searching for advise and optimizations how to handle a string replace (which needs to be called multiple times) and adding these objects to an arraylist (which can contain 1000+ strings) on **large** objects/Strings.

I process these Strings like this:

1.Replace function (called multiple times)

2.All **href links** in the output of step 1 are being extracted and compared using 2 arraylists.

My question would be is there a way to optimize/change these functions so they also work on **large strings?**
When I use these functions on large strings which can contain **1000+ href links** the arraylist (desti_Urls) is not filled/is empty.

However they work perfectly on normal/small Strings.

I appreciate your advise and feedback.

**EDIT:** The ultimate goal is to compare the final arraylist (desti_Urls) with the urls in a **CustomTextView**, if they match set the text color of the links in the CTV to green. PS: The String (output) is set to the CustomTextView.

Replace function:

```
    public static void processSubstring(String inPut) {
            String temP;
            if (inPut.contains("Download Instructions")){
                temP = inPut.substring(inPut.indexOf("Download Instructions:")+31, inPut.length());
                outPut = temP.replace("'", "\"").replace("&#58;", ":").replace("&#46;", ".").replace("</a>", "<br/>" + "</a>");
            }
            else {
                temP = inPut.substring(inPut.indexOf("<a href="), inPut.length());
                outPut = temP.replace("'", "\"").replace("&#58;", ":").replace("&#46;", ".").replace("</a>", "<br/>" + "</a>");
            }
        }
```

Get all href url links and compare them:

```
public static void parseAllLinks(String content) {
        List<String> host_Urls = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> desti_Urls = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> totalUrls = new ArrayList<>();

        desti_Urls.clear();
        totalUrls.clear();
        host_Urls.clear();

        host_Urls.add("a.net");
        host_Urls.add("b.com");
        host_Urls.add("c.to");
        host_Urls.add("d.com");
        host_Urls.add("e.com");
        host_Urls.add("f.to");
        host_Urls.add("g.net");
        host_Urls.add("h.to");
        host_Urls.add("i.net");
        host_Urls.add("j.it");
        host_Urls.add("k.com");
        host_Urls.add("l.com");
        host_Urls.add("m.com");
        host_Urls.add("n.com");
        host_Urls.add("o.com");
        host_Urls.add("p.com");
        host_Urls.add("q.com");
        host_Urls.add("r.net");
        host_Urls.add("s.com");
        host_Urls.add("t.com");
        host_Urls.add("u.to");
        host_Urls.add("v.com");
        host_Urls.add("w.com");
        host_Urls.add("x.net");

        //Extract all url links from output string.
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(outPut);
        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
        for (Element link : links) {
            totalUrls.add(link.attr("abs:href"));

        }
        //Compare them with the host arraylist and add valid
        // host urls to new arraylist (desti_Urls).

        for (int i = 0; i < host_Urls.size(); i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < totalUrls.size(); k++) {
                if (totalUrls.get(k).contains(host_Urls.get(i))) {
                    desti_Urls.add(totalUrls.get(k));
                }
            }
        }
        // However on a LARGE String (output),  desti_Urls is empty.
        System.out.println("HOST LINKS AVAILABLE " + desti_Urls.toString());
    }
```

Comment: Where are you using processSubstring method in your code?

Comment: It`s being called once I press a button (it fetches the String content). "model.getcontent();"

Comment: Use StringBuilder in processSubstring method